# Compare two results and show results PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get two identical IDs and turn them into a name, explaining better I have a table with ID-COMPANY NAME and in the product table ID COMPANY - product name, I would like to match the two and next i will output in excel file.
I tested this code but all the results do not appear to me:

```
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) && ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) )
  {
```

For answer:

db:

1) id - name company - ecc   //Table company 
2) id_product - product - id_company //Table product

Output excel:

Client 1 - id
Client 2 - id

Name     | another information
Client 1 | ecc...  
Client 2 | ecc...

Php:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);   // FIRST CONNECT TABLE
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $query2); // SECOND CONNECT TABLE
if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) && mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0)
{
$output2 .= '
<table class="table" id="table" bordered="1">

';
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{


$output2 .= '
<tr>
<td class="grassetto">Company:</td>
<td class="grassetto">'. $row2["id"].'-'. $row2["nomeazienda"].'</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="grassetto">ID:</td>
<td class="grassetto">'. $mese.'/'.$anno.'</td>
</tr>
';
}
$output2 .= '</table>';

$output .= '
<table class="table ops" id="table" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name Company</th>
<th>Another information</th>

</tr>
';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$output .= '
<tr>
<td align="left">'. $row['id_azienda'] . '</td>
<td align="left">'. $row['nr'] . '</td>



</tr>
';
}
$output .= '</table>';

header('Content-Type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $output2. "\n<br>" .$output."\n";


}
```

So in second output when i call $result i need to compare ID/ID_COMPANY and write a company name

Edit 2:
That is main query

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM  products WHERE  id_company in ('.$company.') AND product ="'.$products.'"';
        }else{
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM  products WHERE  id_company IN ('.$company.') AND product ="'.$products.'" AND last_check LIKE "%'.$anno.'-'.$mese.'%"';
            }

        $query2 = 'SELECT * FROM  company WHERE  id in ('.$company.')';
```

how do you integrate this code?

Comment: Why don't you just join the tables?

Comment: This loop matches up the results row by row, it doesn't find related rows between the two results.

Comment: Show the results of the two queries and what you're trying to put into the Excel file from them.

Comment: @Barmar do you have any solution?

Comment: I still can't understand what you're trying to do. Show the SQL, the results of the two queries and what the resulting spreadsheet should be from that.

Comment: It looks like you're creating an HTML table, not an Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `JOIN` to get the company name from the company ID in the product table in a single query.

```
$query = "
    SELECT c.name, p.product, ...
    FROM company AS c
    JOIN product AS p ON c.id = p.id_company
    WHERE c.id in ($company) AND p.product = '$product'";
```

Comment: Yes, this just replaces the two queries you were doing.

Comment: You can't have `else` without `if`.